# выборка вне диапазона

Tags: php, mysql

Как из БД mysql выбрать запись которая вне диапазона `BETWEEN`

есть выборка

```
$res = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT visits.*, geoip.* FROM visits,geoip WHERE visits.date BETWEEN $data1 AND $data2 
    AND INET_ATON(visits.ip) BETWEEN start_ip_num AND end_ip_num");
```

это выбирает `ip` с таблицы `visits` между диапазонам `start_ip_num AND end_ip_num` из таблицы `geoip`

а нужно выбрать `ip` с таблицы `visits` которая **не входит** в диапазон `start_ip_num AND end_ip_num`

Comment: а почему не `NOT BETWEEN` ?

Comment: если делаю через NOT BETWEEN то в цикле 105 тысяч раз выводятся IP из таблицы visits

Comment: Если одну запись, то к запросу с NOT BETWEEN добавьте еще LIMIT 1.

Comment: так выводит один раз все IP из таблицы visits

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, правильно вопрос. Из "а нужно выбрать ip" и "которая не входит" следует, что нужна одна запись.

Answer (score 1):

Так же как в РНР

```
AND !(INET_ATON(visits.ip) BETWEEN start_ip_num AND end_ip_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

согласно [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-between):

> выражение **not between** минимум **and** максимум

что аналогично конструкции:

> **not** (выражение **between** минимум **and** максимум).